# Datawindows are not displaying in Powerbuilder exe

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I'm building a program in Powerbuilder 2019 R2.  I have a number of windows that have datawindows. On my machine where I deployed the exe, I can see the datawindows, but for some reason when I run the exe on my VMs, the window itself opens but the data windows are missing.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have the PowerBuilder runtimes been installed on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance there are no printer drivers installed, or no default printer set? The display of the DW is heavily dependent on the printer driver.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are the data window objects dynamically assigned at run time?  If so you may need to add them to a pbr file prior to compile.